# How Do I append CoreData Object with Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'd like to add myplaceworks from server to coredata
Here is my coredata object

```
private var user: [User]?
private var myPlaceOfWorks: [MyPlaceOfWorks]?
private var context = sharedManagedObjectContext()
```

and I tried this
workplace of parameter is already made class.

this class controls array in json

```
func addInfo(workplace: [Sub_JsonModel_MyPlaceOfWorks], rtnvalue: String) ->
(User?, MyPlaceOfWorks?) {

    guard let newUser: User = 
NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("User",  
inManagedObjectContext: self.context) as? User else{
        return (nil, nil)

    }

    guard let newWorkPlace: MyPlaceOfWorks = 
NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("MyPlaceOfWorks", 
inManagedObjectContext: self.context) as? MyPlaceOfWorks else {
        return (nil, nil)
    }

    newUser.rtnvalue = rtnvalue

    for one in workplace {

        newWorkPlace.activeyn = one.ActiveYN
        newWorkPlace.basic = one.Basic
        newWorkPlace.beacon = one.Beacon
        newWorkPlace.cpiseq = one.CPISEQ
        newWorkPlace.cpmpoweq = one.CPMPOWSEQ
        newWorkPlace.companyname = one.CompanyName
        newWorkPlace.etime = one.ETime
        newWorkPlace.gps_latitude = one.GPS_latitude
        newWorkPlace.gps_longitude = one.GPS_longitude
        newWorkPlace.placename = one.PlaceName
        newWorkPlace.stime = one.STime
        newWorkPlace.wifi = one.Wifi
        self.myPlaceOfWorks?.append(newWorkPlace)
        print("newWorkPlace \(newWorkPlace)")
        print("myPlaceOfWorks \(myPlaceOfWorks)")
    }

    self.saveContext { 
        //action
        print("newUser:: \(newUser)")

    }
    return (newUser, newWorkPlace)
}

private func saveContext(completion: (() -> Void)?) {
    do {
        try self.context.save()
        if let handler = completion {
            NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock({ () -> Void in
                handler()
            })
        }
    } catch let error {
        print("can not save context \(error)")
    }
}
```

I can get rtnvalue but, I can't get myPlaceOfWorks array object!
It is just nil 
How can I try this?

Comment: `insertNewObjectForEntityForName` providing a valid entity returns always a non optional object, the `guard` expressions are actually not necessary.

Comment: `private var myPlaceOfWorks: [MyPlaceOfWorks]?` gives `nil` if you don't initialise it before line `self.myPlaceOfWorks?.append(newWorkPlace)`

Comment: @vadian thank u :)

Comment: @zcui93 oh..thank u very much !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've created only one object of `MyPlaceOfWorks` class and then rewriting properties of this object in the loop. Instead you need to create new instance on each loop iteration.

```
for one in workplace {
    if let newWorkPlace: MyPlaceOfWorks = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("MyPlaceOfWorks", inManagedObjectContext: self.context) as? MyPlaceOfWorks {
        newWorkPlace.activeyn = one.ActiveYN
        newWorkPlace.basic = one.Basic
        newWorkPlace.beacon = one.Beacon
        newWorkPlace.cpiseq = one.CPISEQ
        newWorkPlace.cpmpoweq = one.CPMPOWSEQ
        newWorkPlace.companyname = one.CompanyName
        newWorkPlace.etime = one.ETime
        newWorkPlace.gps_latitude = one.GPS_latitude
        newWorkPlace.gps_longitude = one.GPS_longitude
        newWorkPlace.placename = one.PlaceName
        newWorkPlace.stime = one.STime
        newWorkPlace.wifi = one.Wifi
        self.myPlaceOfWorks?.append(newWorkPlace)
    }
}
self.saveContext { 
    //action
    print("newUser:: \(newUser)")

}
```

And as zcui93 has mentioned in comments you need to instantiate your `myPlaceOfWorks` variable:

```
private var myPlaceOfWorks = [MyPlaceOfWorks]()
```

Comment: oh my...thanks a lot. It was really the first step problem...:(